# How to read multiple files on C++

Tags: c++, readfile

My problem is :

> First read a file named `symbols.txt`. This file consist of many
>   lines, each line consist of 2  elements : an uppercase letter and a
>   string, this file is ended by a hash(`#`).
>
> Second read a file named `dict.txt`. This file consist of many
>   words(string) . Ended by a hash(`#`)
>
> Third read  a file named `handin.txt`. This file consist of some
>   numbers which you're gonna working on it. Ended by a hash(`#`)
>
> Print your output in a file named `handout.txt`

This is my code but I'm not sure that I let in read the input right. Please check it for me. Thanks a lot.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    freopen("symbols.txt" , "r" , stdin);

         //  input the letter and the string 

    char X ; string Y ;

    while(cin >> X >> Y && X != '#' )  {
         // my code goes here
    }

    freopen("dict.txt" , "r" , stdin) ;

          // input the strings here 

    freopen("handin.txt", "r" , stdin);

         // input the numbers here


    / *

          Here is my code 

    * /

    freopen("handout.txt" , "w" , stdout);

    // let in print the output here



}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Got it, but can I know that I write the reading files code right please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
```

Don't do this. [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31816096/4093378)

---

```
using namespace std;
```

Don't do this either. [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452738/4093378)

---

```
freopen("symbols.txt" , "r" , stdin);
```

This is very bad! You're using [`std::freopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/freopen) to associate a file with `stdin`. Then later on, you're using [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) to read from the file. What you're doing is very "hacky" and this might work sometimes but not always. `stdin` (from C) and `std::cin` (from C++) are not required to be linked like this. `freopen` is a C API so you shouldn't use it in C++ anyway.

What you should do is open an input file stream ([`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)) and read from that. That might look a little bit like this:

```
#include <string> // std::string
#include <fstream> // std::ifstream std::ofstream
#include <iostream> // std::cerr

int main() {
  std::ifstream symbols("symbols.txt");
  if (!symbols.is_open()) {
    // There was a problem opening the symbols file
    // Maybe it was missing
    // You should end the program here and write an error message
    std::cerr << "Failed to open \"symbols.txt\"\n";
    // returning an error code of 0 means "everything is fine"
    // returning anything else means "something went wrong"
    return 1;
  }

  // Try to choose more descriptive names than "X" and "Y"
  char X;
  std::string Y;
  while (symbols >> X >> Y && X != '#') {
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

You code will be clearer if you create a new `std::ifstream` for each file you open (rather than reusing the same one). Error checking is important. You should make sure to check that the file actually opened before using it. To write your output to `"handout.txt"`, you would use an output file stream ([`std::ofstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream)) instead.

---

There's something that might trip you up. Take this `"symbols.txt"` file:

```
A many words
B on the same line
C could cause problems
#
```

If we try to read it using the current code, we run into trouble:

```
symbols >> X >> Y;
// X is 'A'
// Y is "many" rather than "many words" as you might expect
```

If there's only one word on each line then this shouldn't be an issue, but if there are multiple words, then you might need to use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). `std::getline` does what it says on the tin. It reads the whole line and writes it to the given string.

You'd use it like this:

```
while (symbols >> X && X != '#' && std::getline(symbols, Y)) {
  // ...
}
```

---

Please make sure you understand the code (read some of the links) before you copy it off of StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would try to stop using those kind of code. Thanks again for helping

Comment: @JenniferWilson If my answer was helpful, please upvote and accept the answer (click the tick button).

Comment: Yeah I already did, it's really helpful. Thank you. Btw if you're kind enough, can you help me how to write a better code or this problem please. This is the original of http://orac.amt.edu.au/cgi-bin/train/problem.pl?set=aic03&problemid=23 .

Comment: @JenniferWilson Well I can't write the code for you. If you have a go at the problem and get stuck, then you can post another question.

Comment: Thank you. I think I would try working on it instead :D.

Comment: @JenniferWilson If have a **working** solution to the problem and you want to know how you can improve, you could post your code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for guiding, i'm still new to stackoverflow and coding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you show me how do ou use ofstream pls ?? I use std:: cout to print out the output in the file but pretty sure that was incorrect

Comment: @JenniferWilson You can use `std::ofstream` in the same way that I used `std::ifstream` in the example. The only difference is that you use `<<` to write to the file (similar to how you would use `std::cout`). I can edit the answer if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Thank you I can use it normally now, thank you so much for being so supportive <3